# How to fill above the fold at different breakpoints

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, breakpoints

So I've spotted a few sites lately where the background above the fold always perfectly crops to the viewport. For example - if you look at http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/ or http://simplesimple.co/currency/ on a mobile, tablet or desktop device the background image always fills the viewport even at different orientations.

It's not as simple as adding a `max-width: 100%` to the image as this would only fill horizontally. My first thoughts are that it is the art-direction use case, where breakpoints target different crops of the image. It seems like a lot of work to achieve this effect though so I wonder if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/, the main banner image has been added as a background image and its background-size property has a value of cover which will stretch the image to fit the screen at any size.

Then there's tricks like setting the main section tag to have a display property set to table which allows its child div (containing title and sub title) to be vertically centered with display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle

Its built on twitter bootstraps framework which has grids and media queries built right in allowing for different images to be added via the background-image property for each screen size